# How can I configure Azure to publish screenshots of failed Cypress tests when I cancel the Azure Pipeline run?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cypress

I currently run a Cypress build on and Azure DevOps pipeline. I have it configured to publish screenshots of failing tests when the run is completed (or fails). If I cancel the run none of the screenshots are published.

How can I configure the Azure pipeline to publish screenshots of any failing tests when the run is cancelled or fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use `always` condition instead of what you have now.

[image]

Link is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#always)